# Get the second tag value from xml data

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

What is the procedure to get the exact second value from the XML tree?

```
<Dbtag>
    <Dbtag_db>HGNC</Dbtag_db>
    <Dbtag_tag>
        <Object-id>
            <Object-id_str>HGNC:7</Object-id_str>
        </Object-id>
    </Dbtag_tag>
</Dbtag>
<Dbtag>
    <Dbtag_db>Ensembl</Dbtag_db>
    <Dbtag_tag>
        <Object-id>
            <Object-id_str>ENSG00000175899</Object-id_str>
        </Object-id>
    </Dbtag_tag>
</Dbtag>
```

I use the following script to get the value.

```
for child in root.findall('Dbtag/Dbtag_tag/Object-id/Object-id_str'):
        print(child.text)
```

The output I get is

> HGNC:7
>
> ENSG00000175899

How to get the only the second value of  tag

Comment: `findall()` returns a list. Just get the second item of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<r><Dbtag>
    <Dbtag_db>HGNC</Dbtag_db>
    <Dbtag_tag>
        <Object-id>
            <Object-id_str>HGNC:7</Object-id_str>
        </Object-id>
    </Dbtag_tag>
</Dbtag>
<Dbtag>
    <Dbtag_db>Ensembl</Dbtag_db>
    <Dbtag_tag>
        <Object-id>
            <Object-id_str>ENSG00000175899</Object-id_str>
        </Object-id>
    </Dbtag_tag>
</Dbtag></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
sec_id = root.findall('.//Object-id_str')[1].text
print(sec_id)
```

output

```
ENSG00000175899
```